# Integral with respect to a CDF $F(x)$ mutiplied by $x$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral

I recently saw a mathematical expression of the following

$$\int^\infty_xdF(z)z.$$

It looks like a Riemann–Stieltjes integration of $1$ with respect to a function $F(z)z$. Here, $F$ is a CDF and it is assumed to have a support $\underline z$ to infinity.

What confuses me is if $F$ is differentiable, we may express the above integration as

$$\int^\infty_xf(z)z+F(z)dz$$

which is equivalent to $$\int^\infty_xf(z)zdz+\int^\infty_xF(z)dz.$$
Applying the integration by parts on the second term, we end up with the following expression:
$$\int^\infty_xf(z)zdz+F(z)z|^\infty_{z=x}-\int^\infty_xf(z)zdz=F(z)z|^\infty_{z=x}$$

However, we can't evaluate this term because of the infinite component.

My question is: Can we say the function $\int^\infty_xdF(z)z$ is well defined for such a CDF that has an unbounded support? Or is there any problem in my reasoning?

Comment: When the CDF has a density $f$ the integral is just $\int_z^{\infty} zf(z)dz$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is a CDF, then $0 \leq F(z) \leq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$. So the upper bound on your first integral shouldn't be $\infty$, and indeed shouldn't be greater than $1$, since you're integrating with respect to the differential $dF$, and the values of $F$ don't exceed 1. The *support* of $F$ may be unbounded, but the *range* of $F$ is not. But instead of

$\int_x^\infty zdF$,

we could consider

$\int_x^1 zdF$,

for example.

Then, as @Kavi Rama Murthy said, if the probability density function is $f$ and the CDF is $F$, this means that

$\frac{dF}{dz} = f$.

So then it's just a variable substitution in the integral. If we assume that $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0, 1)$ is *strictly* increasing (which is the case for many CDFs, for example the CDF of the normal distribution), then it has an inverse $F^{-1}: (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Because $F$ is a CDF, we also know that $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}F(z) = 1$, and thus $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}F^{-1}(x) = \infty$. Therefore we have

$\int_x^1 zdF = \int_{F^{-1}(x)}^{\infty} z(\frac{dF}{dz})dz = \int_{F^{-1}(x)}^\infty zf(z)dz$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, you mean the initial integration $\int^\infty_x dF(z)z$ cannot be properly defined, right?

Comment: You're welcome! If I'm understanding your question correctly, then yes, that's right. It's undefined for values of the upper bound greater than 1, in the same way that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^1 \text{ln}(x)dx$ is not defined, but $\int_0^1\text{ln}(x)dx = -1$ is.